# How to override newsletter phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm currently working on `Magento 2.1` theme. I'm trying to change the newsletter template and want to change it in our theme.

I have copied the `subscribe.phtml` file from

`[ROOT]/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates`

to

`[ROOT]/app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Module_Newsletter/templates`

and make the require changes but they are not reflecting on browser.

Although I have tried with `Magefan_Blog` extension the `phtml` override works correctly.

Also I have `clean/flush` cache and deploy the content again but still not get refection.

Any one have idea about the issue, please suggest.

Comment: Tried to delete `var/view_preprocessed`?

Comment: Tried, still not working.

Comment: Have you applied below suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in created folder

[ROOT]/app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/**Module**_Newsletter/templates

Change it to

[ROOT]/app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/**Magento**_Newsletter/templates

Rename **Module** folder to **Magento**

Chekc it, now working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you're doing seems to be correct, if you're clearing and flushing cache correctly as a last resort you can delete pub/static/ content and regenerate the static content.

Comment: I have did that(deleted the pub/static and regenerated the static content) also but still same issue.